# How to look for a String that match one in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make an SQL command that look for a String in the database table that match one of the strings containing in my array.

```
//this is my array
$liste_des_themes=array("Préfectures et sous-préfectures","Mairie","Banque");
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM etablissements where type IN $liste_des_themes');//i tried this but seems not working
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $libelle);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "$id $libelle<br/>";
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: try ... `$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM etablissements where type IN ('".implode("','", $liste_des_themes)."');`

Comment: @Rufinus add answers as answers, clarifying questions and insights as comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an `IN` list in the correct format:

```
$liste_des_themes=array("Préfectures et sous-préfectures","Mairie","Banque");
$in_list = "'".implode("','", $liste_des_themes)."'";
$stmt = 
 $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM etablissements where type IN ('.$in_list.')');
```

Comment: +1 although I would add a `array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $liste_des_themes )` since I'm not sure if he really only wants to look for these static text pieces :/ besides: don't forget the `$` in front of the `liste_des_themes` variable

Comment: I would consider looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534377/php-mysqli-where-in so that you can bind your array contents and not worry about SQL injection.