# How to deliver params for SELECT with IN in mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

My prepared query looks like this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT $t1.id FROM $t1 WHERE $t1.name IN (?)";
```

When I try:

```
   $stmt = Sql::$select->prepare($sql);
   $string="'aaa','bbb','ccc'";
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $string);
```

...it doesn't return the expected results. It treats the string as one name and not many separate names.  How can it be solved?

The rest of the function:

```
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
   return $stmt;
```

Comment: i have no prior experience in prepared statements, but i've experienced this problem while using stored procedures. Probably you need to bind each argument in the IN statement.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean @KhaleelAKarim, but i cant do it - the number of names in the string is unknown

Comment: what is `Sql`?, assuming that `Sql::$select` is your connection object, what is the message in `Sql::$select->error` (after the prepare)?

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534377/php-mysqli-where-in)

Comment: well, it dosent any more returns error -but the work is still not being done - it takes the whole string as one name. when i put the string hard coded - it works as expceted. I think i will just do so, and avoid the bind.

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives) available, Please see the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try altering query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT $t1.id FROM $t1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET($t1.name, ?)>0";
$stmt = Sql::$select->prepare($sql);
$string='aaa,bbb,ccc';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $string);
```

And this solution is not reliable.
Please see  [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Correct method is to use separate placeholders for each element in the IN statement.

Another suggestion, get rid of the IN statement and run through  a loop in php to generate the query and bind the params.

Comment: it doesnt bring the result (still treat the string as one long name..)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the bind_param function with 's' threats the parameter as a single string, so it is basically transforming your query to:

```
"SELECT $t1.id FROM $t1 WHERE $t1.name IN (''aaa','bbb','ccc'')";
```

A quick fix would be to change the string variable to:

```
$string="aaa','bbb','ccc";
```

*Note: without the leading/trailing quotes (you can make this using `trim($string, "'")`*

**You may also try inverting the quotes: using `"` instead of `'`** if this does not work.

A more reliable and robust solution is to change the query to incude a `?` for each string (using arrays with `expolode() / implode()` php functions.

Comment: Sorry but you've seriously misunderstood how prepared statements work.