# Replacing "?" in a string by values from array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to replace every "?" in string by values from array. Each "?" is the next value from array.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do the following:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ? AND language = ?';
$values = array('1', 'en');
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $query = preg_replace('/\?/', '\''.$value.'\'', $query, 1);
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($query, true).'</pre>';
```

Would like to do that with native PHP (not a PDO extension).

Comment: Just use PDO? What are you trying to achieve? Subtle SQL Injection?

Comment: "*Would like to do that with native PHP (not a PDO extension)*" - PDO is as "native" to PHP as any other MySQL driver..

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel mate. Just use PDO. PDO is as much of an extension as `mysql_*` functions are.

Comment: @MMM - moreso, PDO isn't deprecated

Comment: @AndVla define "better" please. Does this code work? If so - what certainly you don't like in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binding

in PDO

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
                      FROM fruit
                      WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindValue(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

http://php.net/manual/pl/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

in mysqli

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

if you want to do it in STUPID way you can use loop or recursion

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ? AND language = ?";
$params = array('param', 'param2');
while(preg_match('/\?/', $select)) $select = str_replace("?", array_shift($params),     $select);
```

but it's stupid

Comment: Thank you. The only reason I'm trying to do that is because i want to print the full query with values on execution fail. Thank you any way ;)

Answer (score 2):

Mysqli and PDO are as native as it gets with PHP.

You can use [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) from `mysqli` to accomplish this. Example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ? AND language = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('is', 1, "en");
```

In this case the `i` and `s` are referencing the type of the parameter, as seen in this table (available in link):

```
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

Comment: What letter should I use to bind an array to be used with `IN()` statement?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: As you can see in [this post](http://no2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#103622), there are some downsides on using `IN()` with `mysqli` due to the way `MySQL` handles prepared statements. Should mention that this post is 2 years old though.

Comment: I am curious, you you use mysqli yourself?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I do, though I mainly write programs with `java`. In this case I would write a helper function to bind them individually. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534377/php-mysqli-where-in) is a question on exactly this issue.

Comment: Please forgive my curiosity, but did you try any solution from there?

Comment: No, though honestly I haven't run into any case recently in which I needed to use the `IN` operator from SQL (since I don't work that much with PHP anymore). 
I'm curious, do you happen to know the 'right' way to solve an issue like this?

Comment: Yes. You need to add something like this `$rvalues = array(); foreach($values as $value) $rvalues[] = &$value;` to the only proper answer there (call_user_func one). but the resulting amount of code exceeds any limits of sanity in my opinion. So, I count mysqli prepared statements pretty unusable for the real life usage.

Comment: You're right. Normally I don't use prepared statements with `mysqli` because I usually concatenate (my PHP-apps are mainly used in a private environment where I don't need to protect my database). Nevertheless, you may have convinced me here to consider `PDO` in the future ;)