# Prepared statement WHERE IN clause behaving unexpected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Okay so i am rewriting some old queries, but the WHERE IN clause aint working like it used to in my old SQL? it basically only take "1" from the checked variable

```
    $checked = "1,2,3";
```

New prepared statement

```
    $stmt = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT id FROM rating WHERE category IN (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $checked);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $randomArr;
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $id . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
```

Old Query which works

```
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM rating WHERE category IN ($checked)";
    $result_user_stemmer = $dbCon->query($sql);
    $arr_alle_billeder;
    while ($obj = $result_user_stemmer->fetch_object()) {
        // for hver user_source billedet IKKE skal vises
        echo $obj->id . "<br>";
    }
```

Example output link [here](http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/TESTING/test.php)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534377/php-mysqli-where-in?noredirect=1&lq=1