# Multiple values in where with prepared SQL-Statements?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-injection

Is there a way to select multiple values with prepared statements in (My-)SQL?

I'm trying to select a couple of rows from a table with the IN-keyword, something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 where id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

The "1, 2, 3" should be passed as a parameter of the statement.
Is this possible with PHP/PDO or do I have to concaterate the values and insert it directly in the statement (I've got a bad feeling about this because of injections).

Comment: I think the answer is here: [stackoverflow.com/MySQL Prepared statements with a variable size variable list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of "something" that comes from the user, you can build a list of placeholders with `array_fill`, generate a string like `"?, ?, ?, ..."` by calling `implode` on the array. Alternatively you can make sure everything in the array is an integer (using `intval`, for example) and use it directly to build the query.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass in an array of integers, and then do String.Join to bring them together within your prepared statement.  You can't inject anything into an integer!

Answer (score -1):

Try passing you in-list as aconcatenated string and do this (not very performant but it should work: I think I saw an answer from Joel Spolsky somewhere using this technique):

```
SELECT * FROM table where concat('|',id,'|') like '%|1|2|3|%'
```

Comment: -1 Terrible idea.  No way Joel recommended this.  What if your |1|2|3| values are dynamic?

Comment: now I've found it - he got 28 upvotes for it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337817#337817

Comment: @Dave K: Joel's answer is proof that people will blindly vote (and accept answers) based on who you are rather than the content provided.