# Pass by reference problem with PHP 5.3.1

Tags: reference, mysqli, php

Ok, this is a weird problem, so please bear with me as I explain.

We upgraded our dev servers from PHP 5.2.5 to 5.3.1.

Loading up our code after the switch, we start getting errors like:

`Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in /home/spot/trunk/system/core/Database.class.php on line 105`

the line mentioned (105) is as follows:

```
call_user_func_array(Array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $passArray);
```

we changed the line to  the following:

```
call_user_func_array(Array($stmt, 'bind_param'), &$passArray);
```

at this point (because `allow_call_time_pass_reference`) is turned off, php throws this:

`Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /home/spot/trunk/system/core/Database.class.php on line 105`

After trying to fix this for some time, I broke down and set `allow_call_time_pass_reference` to on.

That got rid of the `Deprecated` warning, but now the `Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference` warning is throwing every time, **with or without** the referencing.

I have zero clue how to fix this. If the target method was my own, I would just reference the incoming vars in the func declaration, but it's a (relatively) native method (mysqli).

Has anyone experienced this? How can I get around it?

Thank you.

Comment: Also, in the code above $stmt is an object returned from mysqli::prepare

Comment: I also had this problem and found [this](https://sixohthree.com/1486/migrating-to-php-5-3-call_user_func_array) blog post that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are passing an array of elements ($passArray). The second item *inside* the passed array needs to be a reference, since that is really the list of items you are passing to the function.

Comment: Actually you are right. However referencing that var does not help either. Hmmmm

Comment: Ok, fixed this by creating a dummy array, referencing the values from the main. It's quite sad that this was required to be honest. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Dear Spot I have a similar problem. do you have any suggestion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290490/mysqli-prepared-statements-error?noredirect=1#comment35651490_23290490

Comment: This answer correctly identifies the problem, but definitely see the below answer by @Dominic for the solution.

Answer (score 45):

I just experienced this same problem, calling bind_param via call_user_func_array and passing an array of parameters.  The solution is to modify the values in the array to be referenced. It's not elegant but it works.

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($passArray));

function makeValuesReferenced($arr){
    $refs = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    return $refs;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, be aware that there is a bug with PHP 5.3.1 concerning references and all `call` family of functions:

> [PHP Bugs #50394: Reference argument converted to value in __call](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50394)

The behavior you are seeing might be a result of this bug and any attempt to fix it code wise may cause problems in the long run.

The problem has been fixed in the SVN version of PHP. Until 5.3.2 is released, you may compile a new version for use, or downgrade to an earlier version.

Answer (score 3):

We were experiencing this same problem with this code:

```
call_user_func(array($strCartHandler, 'CartPurchaseEvent'), $strCartEvent, $objToUser, null, $this);
```

My solution was to just skip `call_user_func` altogether and do this:

```
$strCartHandler::CartPurchaseEvent($strCartEvent, $objToUser, null, $this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what is deprecated is passing a reference through a function. In the function definition you do something like:

```
function(&$arg) {

}
```

This doesn't help you much but you probably need not pass the reference anyway. I guess you could try a wrapper function.

```
function wrapper($stmt, &$passArray) {
    call_user_func_array($stmt, $passArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `mysqli_bind_param()` and `mysqli_bind_result()` functions are very awkward to use.  I've encountered the same difficulty as you describe using them in combination with `call_user_func_array()`

My workaround was to stop using mysqli and instead use PDO_mysql.  It has a much easier usage:

```
$pdoStmt->execute( $passArray );
```

Comment: I thought PDO_mysql was deprecated?

Comment: No, not at all.  What in the world gave you that idea?

Comment: @Spot: `php_mysql.so` is not recommended (not deprecated), `pdo_mysql.so` is very much recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This will helps:

```
<?php
call_user_func_array(Array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array(&$passArray));

function bind_param ($val)
{
    $val = (is_array($val)) ? $val[0] : $val;

    // operations...
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The second paramer Must be an array. apparently  this was only enforced in 5.3

Answer (score -1):

I've got a similar problem, the current code didnt work:

```
$query="Select id,name FROM mytable LIMIT ?,?";
$params=Array('ii');
array_push($params,$from_var);
array_push($params,$to_var);
...
$stmt=$link->prepare("$query");
$ref=new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
$method=$ref->getMethod("bind_param");
$method->invokeArgs($stmt,$params);
...
```

It told that "Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given"

And then, in despair, I've tried to take $from_var and $to_var in quotes. And it worked!

```
$params=Array('ii');
array_push($params,"$from_var");
array_push($params,"$to_var");
```

Hope, it will help somebody, good luck :)