# Deletion of multiple fields fail

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I want to be able to delete multiple users from the database, but the code below fails in some point. What happens is that only the last clicked user (i.e. the last element in the array *$userIds*) gets deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

**from UserModel.php:**

```
public function RemoveUser(Array $userIds) {

    $query = 'DELETE FROM Users WHERE id IN (?)';

    $stmt = $this->m_db->Prepare($query);

    foreach ($userIds as $value) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
    }

    $ret = $this->m_db->DeleteUsers($stmt);

    $stmt->Close();

    return $ret;

}
```

**from Database.php:**

```
public function DeleteUsers(\mysqli_stmt $stmt) {

    if ($stmt === FALSE) {
        throw new \Exception($this->mysqli->error);
    }

    if ($stmt->execute() == FALSE) {
        throw new \Exception($this->mysqli->error);
    }

    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: it looks like you're binding n params to a single slot in the query `?`, is that normal?

Comment: You need to construct the SQL string dynamically, and add a `?` for each array element. I'm looking for a question that addresses this with a good answer...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Ah, I see the problem now. But how could the SQL statement be created dynamically?

Comment: @holyredbeard  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703180/a-prepared-statement-where-in-query-and-sorting-with-mysql. I'll post a better example if I can find one - I know it's out there.

Comment: What you are passing is not a parameter but a part of the query syntax. you can do it in two ways, the ugly and not recommended one is to use the string joins and construct the sql query. Another is, prepare the query dynamically. I am looking for a good answer so I can give you reference to.

Answer (score 3):

As some of the comments suggest, you need to have a `?` for each user id.  Currently, you're attempting to bind each user id to the same parameter, so only the last one will actually apply.

```
$c = Array();
foreach ($userIds AS $u) {
  $c[] = "?";
}
$inPart = "(" . implode(",", $c) . ")";
$query = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE id IN $inPart";
```

Since `bind_param` expects each variable as a separate argument, you'll have to do a little php magic to pass the whole array at once.  You'll have to change your binding loop to:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array_unshift($userIds, 's'));
```

This basically calls `$stmt->bind_param('s', $userIds[0], $userIds[1]....)`

Comment: I don't see $u is being used in the foreach loop?

Comment: It doesn't need to be, I'm just looping over the array to create enough parameters.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. But what about my code where i'm looping through the ids; foreach ($userIds as $value) { $stmt->bind_param('s', $value); }...? When implementing your code that piece of code generates error (Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php-labbar/hp-php/lab3/login/Model/UserHandler.php on line 45)

Comment: Oh, I see you're using mysqli and not PDO, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Tried it but gets the following error: "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php-labbar/hp-php/lab3/login/Model/UserHandler.php on line 44"

Answer (score 2):

I modified [Dan Simons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769710/937624) and managed to get this working.

One of the problems with this solution is that the 2nd parameter in **call_user_func_array** needs to be referenced, with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2045875/937624) is about. The problem is however solved by using the function **makeValuesReferenced**.

The code:

```
public function RemoveUser(Array $userIds) {

    $c = Array();
    $s = '';

    foreach ($userIds AS $u) {
        $c[] = "?";
        $s.= 's'; 
    }

    $inPart = "(" . implode(",", $c) . ")";
    $query = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE id IN $inPart"; 

    $stmt = $this->m_db->Prepare($query);

    array_unshift($userIds, $s);

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->makeValuesReferenced($userIds));

    $ret = $this->m_db->DeleteUsers($stmt);    // Execution and fetching

    $stmt->Close();

    return $ret;

}

public function makeValuesReferenced(Array $arr) {
        $refs = array();

        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;

}
```