# Mysqli prepared statement : several WHERE clauses and WHERE IN (Array)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to run the query below. It asks me a lot of trouble. In fact, I have several "WHERE" conditions, one that requires the decomposition of an Array.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703264) helped me but it doesn't have several conditions "WHERE" .

```
$array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));

if($request = $this->getConnexion()->prepare('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 IN ('.$clause.') AND col2>=?') or die(mysqli_error($this->getConnexion()))) {

    // The problem starts here
    call_user_func_array(array($request, 'bind_param'), $array);

    $request->bind_param('i', $this->getTime());
    // Until here

    $request->execute();
    $request->bind_result($col1, $col2);
    $request->store_result();

    // Following the code

}
```

Comment: You could add your `$this->getTime()` to the end of your array, before using `call_user_func_array`, or build another `array_fill` using `i` and then implode in the `bind_param`

Comment: What is your issue? It looks like instead of an additional call to `bind_param()`, you should add one more `?` onto the `$clause` array, and add the value of `$this->getTime()`  onto the `$array` array of values, so you are just dealing with one array of params covering both the `IN ()` clause and the other condition.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski , please post your answer, I don't understand what you are thinking about :)

Comment: Ok hold on - I misstated the part about `$clause` above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing here is that you are calling `bind_param()` just once, with an array containing *all* of the parameters you'll need to bind, so your solution will be to just add the additional `WHERE` clause parameter onto your `$array` of values to bind.  The `IN()` clause isn't a special case requiring `call_user_func_array()` separated from other parameters. You call it on *all* of them.

Something is missing though - `bind_param()`'s first parameter is a string of data types. All your types are `i`, so you'll need to use `str_repeat()` to create that.

```
// Eventually, this array will contain the other params too
$array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

// This creates a string of ?,?,?,?... for the IN () clause    
$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));

// Add the additional value onto the $array array
// so the last param is bound with the others.
$array[] = $this->getTime();

$types = str_repeat('i', count($array));

// The params passed to call_user_func_array() must have as references, each subsequent value. Add those in a loop, but start with the $types string
$params = array($types);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $params[] = &$array[$key];
}

if($request = $this->getConnexion()->prepare('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 IN ('.$clause.') AND col2>=?') or die(mysqli_error($this->getConnexion()))) {

    // Then bind_param() is called on all parameters
    // using the $params array which includes types and param references
    call_user_func_array(array($request, 'bind_param'), $params);

    // Execute & fetch.
    $request->execute();
    $request->bind_result($col1, $col2);
    $request->store_result();

    // Following the code
}
```

Comment: What stupidity, I hadn't thought about that at all! Thank you. I tested and I validate your answer

Comment: @zlen Not stupidity. MySQLi in conjunction with `call_user_func_array()` is really complicated. I can never remember how to do it without looking it up, and examples are not often well commented to understand what is actually being done.

Comment: I have now this error : "Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference," I found the issue above, but this don't answer me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045875/pass-by-reference-problem-with-php-5-3-1

Comment: @zlen Okay, that should be sufficient. There was a large portion I overlooked, actually creating the array of references

Comment: Indeed, before you edit your post, I understood that the problem came from the reference, so the 'i' number. You explanation is very good. I test that