# PDO updates only one row when used with placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an array which holds multiple ids's, and i need to to update multiple columns. i am using MySQL `IN()` for that. the problem is when i use the query below it works perfectly fine.

```
public function available($value, $propertyId = array()) {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('UPDATE properties p SET p.status = :status WHERE p.id IN('.implode(',',$propertyId).')');
    $sth->bindParam(':status',$value);
    return $sth->execute();
}
```

as the above query is not using any placeholders for second argument `$propertyId` i assume it is wrong way to do so. but when i use either named or unnamed place holder in the query it will update only 1 row. for example the below codes update only one row.

```
//This will update only one row.
//Using Named Place Holder
public function available($value, $propertyId = array()) {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('UPDATE properties p SET p.status = :status WHERE p.id IN(:propertyId)');
    $sth->bindParam(':status',$value);
    $sth->bindParam(':propertyId', implode(',', $propertyId));
    return $sth->execute();
}
```

Or

```
//Using Unnamed Place Holder.
public function available($value, $propertyId = array()) {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('UPDATE properties p SET p.status = ? WHERE p.id IN(?)');
    return $sth->execute(array($value, implode(',', $propertyId)));
}
```

i tried converting converting the array to a string and assigning it to the variable like below.

```
public function available($value, $propertyId = array()) {
    $id = implode(',', $propertyId);
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('UPDATE properties p SET p.status = ? WHERE p.id IN(?)');
    return $sth->execute(array($value, $id));
}
```

even that won't work. what is happening? what am i missing?

thank you

Comment: AFAIK parameterized queries cannot be used with list `IN (...)`, if you don't specify every single element with a placeholder. `IN (?,?,?,? ...)`. Your first query is the way to go, when propertyId only contains integer values.

Comment: You can find solution for similar problem in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Comment: Just to support first comment, `Doctrine` ORM uses `PDO` and generates `(?,?,?,....)` for `IN` queries.

Comment: @culrais, is that first query safe from SQL injections? i don't know but i thought it is unsafe to do it that way.

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar, use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php to escape all data you pass in that query(each value in array, not imploded string) and you will be as safe as with pdo::prepare/bind_param, but of cource a little bit more traffic will be generated to SQL server - each eascape call should be MySql call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, wish it helps.

```
public function available($value, $propertyId = array()) {
    $id_placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($propertyId), '?'));
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('UPDATE properties p SET p.status = ? WHERE p.id IN('.$id_placeholders.')');
    return $sth->execute(array_merage(array($value), $propertyId));
}
```