# Prepare MySQL statement with IN() function

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Now I do:

```
$params = array(1,2,3);
$sql = 'select * from foo where bar in (%s)';

$sql = sprintf($sql, 
    implode(',', $params)
);
```

`$params` is supplied by a user so it's obviously unsafe.
How can I fix this? I would prefer using a framework like Zend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Prepared statements with a variable size variable list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$dbh    = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$params = array(1,2,3);
$values = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?')); // ?,?,?
$sql    = "select * from foo where bar in ($values)";
$stmt   = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

$stmt->execute( $params );
```

By using prepared statements, you avoid the need to escape your data.  You will still need to validate it though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make each array entry safe. Either using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or in your case, just by casting to int. The most generic method would be the following:

```
function quoteString( $string ) {
  return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($string) . "'";
}

$quotedParams = array_map("quoteString", $params);

$sql = sprintf($sql, 
  implode(',', $quotedParams)
);
```

In your case, you could cast to int, so you could do it like this:

```
$intParams = array_map("intval", $params);

$sql = sprintf($sql, 
  implode(',', $intParams)
);
```