# How to use prepared statements in queries with an IN clause in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I need to make a simple query

```
$array_of_ids = array();
//poulate $array_of_ids, they don't come from another db but from Facebook
//so i can't use a subquery for the IN clause
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT id from table where id IN (%d, %d)", $array_of_ids [0], $array_of_ids [1]);
```

The question is, if i have 200 elements in the array, what is the correct way to handle this?Do i have to manually build the query with 200 `%d`? I need this query because i must "sync" my database with facebook data and i have to check if the user i have in the db are present, update those that are present, insert new users and delete those that are not my friend.

Comment: See if [this question][1] doesn't answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Answer (score 4):

If you know for certain that the array elements are numeric:

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN ("
  . implode(',',$array_of_ids) . ")");
```

Otherwise, you can use the `vsprintf` form of `prepare` to pass in the array of parameters:

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id IN ("
  . str_repeat("%d,", count($array_of_ids)-1) . "%d)" , $array_of_ids);
```

Comment: Kinda defeating the whole purpose of prepared statements there, aren'tcha.

Comment: You can do an `implode(',', array_map('intval', $array_of_ids))` to ensure that they are, in fact, numeric.

Comment: Fair points; also showing an alternative approach in my revised answer.

Comment: I'm just curious, why don't you do `str_repeat("%d,", count($array_of_ids)) . ")"` ? Is there some edge case i'm missing?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: You'd end up with a trailing comma you'd need to strip.

Comment: :) thanks that's what i was missing

Comment: @eggyal - Then how about `implode(',', array_pad(array(), count($array_of_ids), '%d'))`? See here: http://viper-7.com/kfNFfM

Comment: @JosephSilber: Yes, that would work... but almost certainly less performant to iteratively construct an array solely for the purpose of then imploding its contents into a string...

Comment: In the situation I have where the array is strings rather than decimal I think the second alternative in this solution 8adapted to %s of course) is the best.  Though you should handle the case that the array is empty as a special case first I think

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is a *good* approach, but you could do it in this fashion:

```
$sql = "SELECT id from table where id IN (" 
     . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array_of_ids), "%d"))
     . ")";

call_user_func_array(array($wpdb, 'prepare'), $array_of_ids);
```

This builds a string with the appropriate number of `%d`, then uses `call_user_func_array` to do it dynamically.

That said, I'm not sure this is really a case where prepared statements are worth the hassle, given how easy it is to sanitise integers.

Comment: array_map() does the trick nicely i think, but if i use array map in that way i could easily skip the prepared statement :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dynamic sql is the way here. Fortunately, integers are easy to not screw up with.

```
$vals = array_filter(array_map('intval', $vals));
```

make sure you have at least one value and then implode it. Not need for a prepared statement here, just execute the sql.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has no accepted answer yet I'll go with my approach with [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$array_of_ids = array(0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13);

echo "SELECT id from table where id IN (".implode(',', array_filter($array_of_ids,'is_int')).")";
```

will output

```
SELECT id from table where id IN (0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13)
```

while

```
$array_of_ids = array('zero',1,true,2,3,5,8,'thirteen');

echo "SELECT id from table where id IN (".implode(',', array_filter($array_of_ids,'is_int')).")";
```

will output

```
SELECT id from table where id IN (1,2,3,5,8)
```

Please note that `is_int` doesn't work with $_GET variables so use `is_numeric` instead

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id from table where id IN :param");
$query->bindParam("param", "(".implode(',', array_map('intval', $array_of_ids)).")");
```

Comment: Surely `array_map('intval', ...)` guarantees safety from SQL injection?

Comment: Seems to me that if you bind `param`, it'll be SQL-escaped, quoted,  and treated as a string...not as a list of stuff.  Unless MySQL does some magic to interpret strings as lists, this probably won't work.

Comment: $wpdb->prepare() does not actually "prepare" a statement in the database, but rather just sanitizes the parameters. Also your $query->bindParam() call would generate an error as $wpdb->prepare() returns a string and not the PDOStatement object as your answer would suggest

Comment: @thorne51 your comment is not clear. This code works and I don't see how it would fail like you say.
@cHao : Not really, you are building a list from `$array_of_ids` but if one entry contains ",", you may have a fail in your request. Maybe not an SQL injection, but something to work on security side. The "intval" prevents it.