# WordPress prepare SQL query string with IN() for multiple post type and remove backslash(\) from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-injection

Can anybody do this please.

**Now How can I remove backslash(`\`) from SQL?**

Here I want to generate dynamic SQL query string. i can do this in procedural way. but here have some Security Risk because $postType is dynamic data.

```
$postType = array('post', 'product', 'page');
$strPostType = (string) implode("', '", $postType);

//Security Risk because $postType is dynamic data
//$sql = "SELECT `ID` FROM `cb_posts` WHERE `post_status` LIKE 'publish' AND `post_type` IN('" . $strPostType . "')";

 $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `ID` FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts` WHERE `post_status` LIKE 'publish' AND `post_type` IN('%s')", array($strPostType));
 //$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N);
 echo $sql;
```

Result:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `cb_posts` WHERE `post_status` LIKE 'publish' AND `post_type` IN('post\', \'product')
```

**Now How can I remove backslash(`\`) from SQL?**

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I tried but not finding an IDEA.

Comment: this doesn't work that way you have to have a placehoölder for every value in your array so check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501458/5193536  the second proposal

Comment: This is possible for numeric values of array. But not possible for string values of array. **IN (0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13)**

Comment: Need this  **IN('post', 'product')** But Now generated  **IN('post\', \'product')**