# How to check for multiple values in MySQL using IN and a parameter?

Tags: mysql, regex, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm generating a string of values (colors) like so:

```
  'red|green|blue|yellow|orange|black'
```

Can I pass this as a parameter (param_cols) to a MySQL stored procedure and check against it like so:

```
  SELECT tbl.products
  FROM table AS tbl
  WHERE tbl.color IN ( param_cols );
```

**Question**:
Is this possible using a parameter? Should I use IN, LIKE or REGEX?

**EDIT**:
THANKS for the hints. However I'm more concerned about whether I can pass my list of colors as a variable into the stored procedure vs having to insert each color individually?

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
 SELECT tbl.products
 FROM table AS tbl
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(tbl.color , 'red,green,blue,yellow,orange,black');
```

I am not sure [if this can be used with an index](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37564), though.

Comment: Can I do FIND_IN_SET(tbl.color, param_cols ) or not = can I pass the colors as a variable into the stored procedure?

Comment: @frequent : yes you can do... Just create string as red,green,blue,y instead of red|green|blue|. **Can you try and see what happen?**

Comment: @FahimParkar: Thanks. Trying now. I need to set up a standalone storedProc, because there must be something else amiss.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. If you want to make it an answer, I will check!

Answer (score 1):

If your colors have an int index, you're better off using that.

But you're on the right track, you can use IN

```
SELECT tbl.products FROM table as tbl WHERE tbl.color 
IN ('red','green','blue','yellow','orange','black')
```

This will only look for exact matches though.

Comment: But can I pass the string as a varialble or do I need to hardcode the color names in MySQL. So can I pass param_cols=('red, 'green', ...)?

Comment: If you're using another language such as PHP, you can create a string and use that (e.g. $line = "'red','green'";) But if you're using MySQL exclusively, [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) would help you out a lot more than a short comment