# mysql like values with comma

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

Basically, the setup of the table is something like this:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
|   land    |   city   |  perimeter  |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  America  |  Kansas  |      1      |
|  Britain  |  Berlin  |      4      |
|  Japan    |  Tokyo   |      5      |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

My current query:

```
$query = "SELECT land, city, perimeter FROM agents WHERE land LIKE ? OR city LIKE ? OR perimeter LIKE ?";
$params = array("%China%","%Kansas%","%6%");
```

This query works, with this it will return `America,Kansas,1`. However if my `params` will be equal to:

```
$params = array("%China%","%Beijing,London,Kansas,Bali%","%6%");
```

This will not return anything. How can I use `LIKE` in values separated with commas to match at least if one item exists in those comma separated values.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `LIKE` use `REGEXP` (more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).

```
$query = "SELECT land, city, perimeter FROM agents
   WHERE land REGEXP ? OR city REGEXP ? OR perimeter REGEXP ?";
$params = array("^China$","^Beijing|London|Kansas|Bali$","^6$");
```

Comment: What if I have the other way around, the database has the comma separated values then the value on params array is just a single word, will this approach fit?

Comment: yes, except in situation where the word you look for is a substring of another (i.e. you are looking for "York" and there is "New York" in database). to get around this case - include separator character in search.

Comment: Badly need your help amigo, this doesn't work if my `city` on database is `Beijing,London,Kansas,Bali` then in my parameter `"^Beijing|Jakarta$"`. What do I need to adjust? Thanks.

Comment: Remove ^ and $ as these matches begin-of-line and end-of-line respectively. Let it simply be `Beijing|Jakarta`.

Comment: If you want to avoid the "substring problem" I mentioned before you must include separator in search, like this: `,Beijing,|,Jakarta,` and change condition to: `concat(',',city,',') regexp ?`.

Comment: No problem. I'll message you when I will be looking for some cheap apartment in Spain next summer. ;]

Comment: don't worry; just kidding. :]

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass comma separated values and expect them to be grouped properly by the parameter function.

Your query as it stands returns:

`SELECT land, city, perimeter FROM agents WHERE land LIKE 'China' OR city LIKE 'Beijing,London,Kansas,Bali' OR perimeter LIKE '6'`

Which is clearly not what you want.

What you want to do will need to check if any of the parameters is an explodable array through something like `if(count(explode(',', $myArray))>1)` to see if any of the variables passed to the query are arrays containing multiple fields. If they are, you want to run a different query string that checks for multiple `or` statements properly.