# How can I apply linear search in if condition(PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table call *subject*, having a field *subject_name*. Here I want to match *subject_name* with a value, which I have get from global `GET`.

Below shown is the code that I have tried. Here I have get list value from another page.

```
global $list;
if(isset($_GET['U']))
{
    $list=$_GET['U'];
}
```

Now for `subject_name` I have tried below code.

```
    $subject=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM subject');
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($subject))
    if($list==$row["subject_name"])
    {
        //execute this
    }
```

Here how can I match $list value with `subject_name` list?

Comment: What is the problem now??

Comment: Why dont you try getting the match list from the query itself b putting a where condition.?

Comment: He is trying to implement linear search. Thats why..

Comment: Here nothing is happening.If I apply this code like 
if($list='php')
{

}
this is working.But after using $row["subject_name"],nothing is happening.

Comment: Try to echo `$row["subject_name"]` and check what you are getting.

Comment: Based on your past comment (hope it was a typo) you need to use `==` and not `=` to perform a comparison.

Comment: ops sorry. Here mistake in comment not in my code.I have tried like this 
$subject=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM subject');
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($subject))
     if($list==$row["subject_name"])
{
   ///execute this
}

Answer (score 0):

If `$list` is an array which it might well be, you can use an [array search](https://www.php.net/array_search) like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($subject))
{
    $key=array_search($row["subject_name"], $list);
}
```

If it isn't then:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($subject))
{
    if($list==$row["subject_name"])
    {
    //execute this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need rows *not* matching your filter array later in your script, then your should filter your results at query time (in SQL):

*Below example provided for eduction purpose only. **DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!***

```
<?php

mysql_query('SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subject_name IN ("' . implode('","', $list) . ')');
```

... which produces a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM subject WHERE subject_name IN ("subjectA", "subjectB"...)
```

Usual piece of advice:

1. your code (as well as mine above) is [begging for SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), do not use it in a publicly accessible application
2. [do not use the obsolete `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Here is a [nice and safe solution with PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/327384/1446005).