# Using multiple values in MySQL query parameters (... IN ('value', 'value')...)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters

I am connecting to a database on MySQL to read certain data in a VB.NET Form. I am using MySQLCommand parameters to pass in my data, but have been unable to use the `IN` query with multiple values in the parameters. Here is my query (with pointers to commands):

```
SELECT time, method FROM test1 WHERE custPin=@CUST AND dataID=@ID AND method IN (@CALLS)
```

There are upwards of two parameters I need to pass into `@CALL`, which for examples sake will be `test1, test2, test3`. These are stored in a list before being looped through and inserted into a string for the parameter, for example we will call `testList`. Below is my MySQLCommand parameter:

```
dim testList As String = test1 & " " & test2 & " " & test3
mySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@CALLS", MySqlDbType.String).Value = testList
```

I have tried to divide the `testList` using `,`, `'<SPACE>'`, and `''`, but no dice. When dividing it is putting in random `\` into my string.

Is there a better way to use the `IN` MySQL command with multiple values while using MySQL parameters as above?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list). It's in PHP, but it is what you are looking for, I think.

Comment: @bhamby: this is already closed as a duplicate of that ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm going to blame the time it took me to type out the comment. It was only a little bit after you closed it that I commented. :)