# mysql procedure : Result consisted of more than one row with select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I am creating one procedure for my regular repeated job.

Within this, there is one steps to insert multiple rows from one table into temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE `tmpUserList` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `first_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `last_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    ..... some more queries.


        INSERT INTO  tmpUserList ( 
                SELECT  id, user_type,first_name,last_name,  from user  where  id in  (usersId) 
        );


    SELECT * FROM tmpUserList; // return the result
```

But it gives me error :  **Result consisted of more than one row**

Comment: Is this some sort of attempt to find duplicates?

Comment: @P.Salmon nope.Its just inserting some rows in temp table and return the result from temp table by calling procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `INSERT SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tmpUserList(id, user_type,first_name,last_name)
SELECT id, user_type,first_name,last_name 
FROM user  
WHERE id IN (usersId);
```

If `usersId` contains multiple values you could use:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, usersId);  -- table scan
```

Related: [MySQL Prepared statements with a variable size variable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list)

Comment: will it insert multiple rows  from select result using insert into tmpUserList?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN That is exactly what `INSERT SELECT` does. It will insert as many rows as independent `SELECT` returns

Comment: it gives me error : Result consisted of more than one row

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Why are you not posting entire code? You probably have `SELECT ... INTO` statement inside your SP.

Comment: I have copies your answer as it is.no INTO statement

Comment: my bad,there was correction in other statement. Upvoted and accepted @Lukasz