# Convert Javascript Array to MySQL Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, api

i would like to convert a javascript array 
ids = [ 378, 464 ]
to an array that MySQL is successfully parsing.

My SQL query includes the array like this:

```
Do something WHERE id IN ("472", "467").
```

This query works in MySQL Workbench.

I am struggling to get the array in the needed structure. I tried the following javascript structures within my api but i cannot get it to work.

```
("378", "464")
[ 378, 464 ]
('472', '467')
```

MYSQL Error Message:

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
```

Comment: where do you hand over the query?

Comment: You should also consider prepared statements - here's a way to deal with this for a variable-length IN clause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327274/mysql-prepared-statements-with-a-variable-size-variable-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could stringify a stringed value and join all values with comma.

```js
var ids = [378, 464],
    formatted = `(${ids.map(v => JSON.stringify(v.toString())).join(', ')})`;

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: This results in the following query for me: '(\\\"378\\\", \\\"464\\\")' which ends up throwing parsing errors in mysql

Comment: as i aready askes, where do hand over this? please add the wanted format and why the string has escaped backslashes.

Comment: I am inserting this via 
```
db.query(('DO something WHERE id IN ?'), [formatted])

your fix works with:

db.query(('DO something WHERE id IN ' + formatted)

Thanks!

Comment: had you have a look to the linked question in the above comment section?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array#join('", "')` to convert the array into the string format you desire.

```js
var list = ["123", "354"];

if (!list.length) {
  console.log("Empty");
} else {
  var query = `select * from table where id in ("${list.join('", "')}")`;
  console.log(query);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

```js
console.log("(",["378", "464"].toString(),")",);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it: Use join in array `("${arrItems.join('","')}")`

```js
var arrItems = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var strSql = `SELECT * FROM Example WHERE ID IN ("${arrItems.join('","')}")`;
console.log(strSql);
```